# RecyclerView show 50 contacts on every scroll with load more option

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

In my phone 4500+ contacts are available. when i am trying to read all contacts it will take very long time.
My expected output is :
I want to get 50 contacts on every scroll.

Comment: what are you using to get contacts from phone , show some of your code

Comment: what did you try so far show your effort?

Comment: Make service -> get first 50 contacts -> detect end of recyclerview from scroll -> make service -> add new contacts to the previous contacts -> notifydatasetchanged -> repeat the last 4 until you reach the end of contacts

Comment: Right now i am get all contacts code is : ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
        Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME + " ASC");